# I need to make discount depends from Registration date

Tags: apex

I need to create discount and in the future if we need to change discout amount or Years from registration, we need to do this without code changes
My code

```
public with sharing class DiscountAmountTriggerHandler {
    public void beforeInsert(List<Opportunity> TriggeredOpps) {
        
        List<DiscountAmount__mdt> DiscountRecords = [select AccountDiscount__c, YearsSinceReg__c
                                                     from DiscountAmount__mdt ];
        Set<Id> accountIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
            accountIdsSet.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
        accountIdsSet.remove(null);
        
        Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([
            SELECT Id, Registration_Date__c
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id IN :accountIdsSet
        ]);
        
        for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
            Account parentAccount = parentAccountsMap.get(opp.AccountId);
            If (parentAccount.Registration_Date__c != null){
                Date todayDate = Date.today();
                Date RegDay = parentAccount.Registration_Date__c;
                Integer numberOfYears = todayDate.year() - RegDay.year();
                // here should be code which not used numbers, because if client want that discount should be after 6 years, i need chenge code
                if(numberOfYears > 5) {
                    numberOfYears = 5;
                }else if (numberOfYears == 4) {
                    numberOfYears = 3;
                }
                for (DiscountAmount__mdt disc : DiscountRecords){
                    if(numberOfYears == disc.YearsSinceReg__c){
                        opp.Amount = opp.Amount - (opp.Amount*(disc.AccountDiscount__c / 100));
                    }          
                }
            }                    
                
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track with custom metadata. You need to compare the *numberOfYears* with *YearsSinceReg__c* from the mdt and aply logic in the same step.
you also will need a standard discount parameter, so you can calculate the Opps that are not discounted.

```
public with sharing class DiscountAmountTriggerHandler {
    public void beforeInsert(List<Opportunity> TriggeredOpps) {
        
        Object standartDiscaount; //generic representariof of you parameter fos standard discount
        List<DiscountAmount__mdt> DiscountRecords = [select AccountDiscount__c, YearsSinceReg__c
                                                     from DiscountAmount__mdt ];
        Set<Id> accountIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
            accountIdsSet.add(opp.AccountId);
        }
        accountIdsSet.remove(null);
        
        Map<Id, Account> parentAccountsMap = new Map<Id, Account>([
            SELECT Id, Registration_Date__c
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id IN :accountIdsSet
        ]);
        
        for (Opportunity opp : TriggeredOpps){
            Account parentAccount = parentAccountsMap.get(opp.AccountId);
            If (parentAccount.Registration_Date__c != null){
                Date todayDate = Date.today();
                Date RegDay = parentAccount.Registration_Date__c;
                Integer numberOfYears = todayDate.year() - RegDay.year();
                // here should be code which not used numbers, because if client want that discount should be after 6 years, i need chenge code
                for(DiscountAmount__mdt discount : DiscountRecords){
                    if(disccount.YearsSinceReg__c > numberOfYears ){
                        // logic here
                        break;//dont need to check again after its done once
                    }
                    else if(disccount.YearsSinceReg__c <= standartDiscaount ){
                        // logic here
                        break;//dont need to check again after its done once
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```